# How to sample from a predictive distribution of a transformed quantity

Tags: bayesian, monte-carlo

Typically, it's easy to simulate from the predictive distribution for next observation, say $\tilde{y}$, after obatining the posterior distribution for $\theta$. We may first simulate a large number of $\theta$ from its posterior distribution, then plug them into the density function $f(y|\theta)$, from there we could generate predictive samples of $\tilde{y}$.

But what if we want to generate predictive samples of say, log($\tilde{y}$) from its corresponding predictive distribution? Can we just repeat the steps above and then just apply log transformation to the sample of $\tilde{y}$ obtained? Is it legit or not? If so, or not, can anyone supply reasons/theorems as to why that is the case?

Comment: Yes, this is a consequence of the (poorly-named) "Law of the unconscious statistician".

Comment: Sory I thought the Law of the unconscious statistician is only related to computing expected values, does it also apply in generating Bayesian predictive quantities for say g(y)?